# tensorflow random forest regression

Tags: python, tensorflow, regression, random-forest

I would like to implement a simple random forest regression to predict a value. The inputs are some samples with several features, and the label is a value. However, I cannot find a simple example about the random forest regression problem. Thus, I saw the document of [tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/tensor_forest/client/random_forest.py) and I found that:

An estimator that can train and evaluate a random forest.
  Example:

```
  python
  params = tf.contrib.tensor_forest.python.tensor_forest.ForestHParams(
      num_classes=2, num_features=40, num_trees=10, max_nodes=1000)
  # Estimator using the default graph builder.
  estimator = TensorForestEstimator(params, model_dir=model_dir)
  # Or estimator using TrainingLossForest as the graph builder.
  estimator = TensorForestEstimator(
      params, graph_builder_class=tensor_forest.TrainingLossForest,
      model_dir=model_dir)
  # Input builders
  def input_fn_train: # returns x, y
    ...
  def input_fn_eval: # returns x, y
    ...
  estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn_train)
  estimator.evaluate(input_fn=input_fn_eval)
  # Predict returns an iterable of dicts.
  results = list(estimator.predict(x=x))
  prob0 = results[0][eval_metrics.INFERENCE_PROB_NAME]
  prediction0 = results[0][eval_metrics.INFERENCE_PRED_NAME]
```

However, when I follow the example, I got the error on the line,`prob0 = results[0][eval_metrics.INFERENCE_PROB_NAME]`, the error shows that:

```
Example conversion:
est = Estimator(...) -> est = SKCompat(Estimator(...))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RF_2.py", line 312, in <module>
    main()
  File "RF_2.py", line 298, in main
    train_eval(x_train, y_train, x_validation, y_validation, x_test, y_test, num_tree)
  File "RF_2.py", line 221, in train_eval
    prob0 = results[0][eval_metrics.INFERENCE_PROB_NAME]
KeyError: 'probabilities'
```

I think the error occurs on `INFERENCE_PROB_NAME`, and I saw the [document](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/tensor_forest/client/eval_metrics.py). However, I still do not know what the word is to replace `INFERENCE_PROB_NAME`.

I have tried `get_metric('accuracy')` to replace `INFERENCE_PROB_NAME`, it return the error: `KeyError: <function _accuracy at 0x11a06eaa0>`.

I also tried `get_prediction_key('accuracy')` to replace `INFERENCE_PROB_NAME`, it return the error: `KeyError: 'classes'`.

If you know the possible answer, please tell me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are unintentionally doing a classification problem by giving a wrong `num_classes=2` and not changing the default value of `regression=False`.  See the *Parameters* section [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/tensor_forest). Just as a quick test, set `num_classes=0` and `regression=True`, and re-run your code.

Comment: num_classes=0 is not applicable for v1.3.

Answer (score 1):

`num_classes=0` is wrong in tensorflow 1.3.0.

From the link of Mehdi Rezaie, `num_classes` is the number of dimensions in the output of a regression problem.

You have to use `num_classes=1` or bigger value for num_classes.
Or You'll get the error like `ValueError: Invalid logits_dimension 0.`